# Selecting latest record of a duplicate uid

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select the last saved record of a user from a table.Sometimes each user can have a duplicate uid which is the main search criteria but each record has a different id and date-time. If i select it using this

```
  SELECT * from recharges WHERE uid = '$uid' LIMIT 1
```

it returns the first record of the user as oppose to what i want it to retrieve.

Comment: What is the column name for the `datetime` field ?

Comment: It would help to see the actual table structure. This sounds like a database design problem.

Comment: Does table have auto number field?

Comment: what about `ORDER BY ID DESC` ?

Comment: It actually returns an indeterminate/arbitrary result (although in practice, this could often be the 'first'). Remember, rows in SQL have NO order other than that specified by an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to sort the order in descending order by `id` (Assuming it to be your PK, where higher `id` value means latest entry)

```
SELECT * FROM recharges 
WHERE uid = '$uid' 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hi, please can you show me how to update the current user record without updating the other records that share the same uid

Comment: @Emmyz please post a new question with some relevant sample data and expected output.

Comment: @Emmyz do consider upvoting this answer as well . Thanks :)